# Search parameter not working with the API request

Tags: json, dataset

I am new to json and APIs.

This particular dataset I am working with (https://api.cdnjs.com/libraries) is searchable by placing `?search=search_term` after it (like: https://api.cdnjs.com/libraries?search=cloud). But when I use another `json` dataset (http://api.nobelprize.org/v1/prize.json for instance) it gives an error:

```
{ "error":"Using an unknown parameter" }
```

Does this have to do with how the datasets are set up? Methods perhaps? How do I make the other `json` searchable like the initial one (so I can use it in my search app)?

Comment: By searchable do you mean actually getting a response? In that case it depends on the API. Relating documentation should provide you with necessary information to ensure you get the response you need. By the way the second url you've posted provides a response: `{ 'prizes':[......] }`

Comment: This gives an error though: api.nobelprize.org/v1/prize.json?search=search-term

Comment: Where do I find the related documentation?

Comment: Yeah that is because the url is not meant to work with that parameter `?search`. As the error message suggests the latter para. is undefined. You could parse the response in the language you prefer the most to find what you need.

Comment: please check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Navigating to the [main domain](https://www.nobelprize.org/) of the provided url, you will find that the doc reside at https://nobelprize.readme.io/v1.0

To refine your results, as the docs suggest you should use the following parameters (when searching for prizes): `year`, `yearTo`, `category` and `numberOfLaureates`.

Here is an example of a refined search:

Request url: `http://api.nobelprize.org/v1/prize.json?category=physics&year=2017`

Response:

```
{
    "prizes": [{
        "year": "2017",
        "category": "physics",
        "laureates": [{
            "id": "941",
            "firstname": "Rainer",
            "surname": "Weiss",
            "motivation": "\"for decisive contributions to the LIGO detector and the observation of gravitational waves\"",
            "share": "2"
        }, {
            "id": "942",
            "firstname": "Barry C.",
            "surname": "Barish",
            "motivation": "\"for decisive contributions to the LIGO detector and the observation of gravitational waves\"",
            "share": "4"
        }, {
            "id": "943",
            "firstname": "Kip S.",
            "surname": "Thorne",
            "motivation": "\"for decisive contributions to the LIGO detector and the observation of gravitational waves\"",
            "share": "4"
        }]
    }]
}
```

If it wasn't clear enough, I made a request to the API to retrieve data concerning prizes awarded in the physics category in the year 2017.

Comment: Great! So basically instead of ?search (as that's a paramater of the other api) I can change my JS code to have it add ?category=search-term and I will be able to have my app search on the category in this particular json api :)

Thanks for clarifying!

Now how did you find the documentation? Just searched around on the website basically? You can see, I am new to APIs ;)

Comment: Exactly. And yeah I just searched around on the main website. If the API is open you'll always find a 'Developers' or 'API' link around...